# Starting Guest OS slows down computer

Tags: linux, windows-xp, virtualbox, virtualization

I have virtual box 4.2.4 installed in Windows XP SP 3 and Oracle Linux is installed in Virtual box.

When I start linux on Virtual box, I have noticed that both my host and guest machines becomes unresponsive, means it will take a long time to launch a program or open a file.
If I shutdown guest OS, then host OS will become normal.

What could be the reason for this?

I had quite a few improper shutdowns on my guest OS, due to this file system got damaged?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

*Update 1*

Memory Allocation

[image][image][image]

Update 2

Comment: Windows XP is the 32bit version right?  And is the installed Linux 32bit as well?  I think it has to be.

Comment: Are you using the very latest version of virtual box?

Answer (score 1):

If the guest is on the same drive as the host OS, move the guest to an external or a different physical drive and see if the performance improves.  If both OSs are trying to use the same drive, you will have issues.

Also make sure you have not allocated too much RAM or Processors to the guest.

In most cases I have seen, it is hard drive and using an external USB 3, eSATA or even USB2 drive will make a big difference.

Comment: I have added screen shots of my memory allocation as update 1 by editing my question, kindly suggest how much memory should I reduce?

Answer (score 1):

Several reasons.

1. How much memory do you have on your host?
2. How much memory are you
   giving your guest?
3. How many CPU cores do you have on your host?
4. How many are you
   allocating to your guest?

I think you may be giving your guest too much.  The host needs a certain amount of resources to run I/O for the guest.

Comment: I have added screen shots of my memory allocation as update 1 by editing my question, kindly suggest how much memory should I reduce?

Answer (score 1):

The most probable reason for this is lack of operational memory. When this happens the Host OS will try to allocate the required memory for the Guest. At that time, due to insufficient memory resources, the Host will begin swapping/paging. Now you are hitting the hard drive, where this process occurs and everything is s-l-o-w. 
You have two options:

1. reduce the required memory for the Guest OS;
2. upgrade the Host OS RAM (buy more RAM).

Bonne chance!

Comment: How to find out how much memory I have allocated to guest OS?

Comment: I have added screen shots of my memory allocation as update 1 by editing my question, kindly suggest how much memory should I reduce?

Comment: @Polppan - as per your first screenshot you have allocated 1GB for your VM. Now, how much memory you have on the Host OS?

Comment: I have 3GB on my host OS

Comment: OK, so close all your applications, start the VM and post the result here. Does it make a difference? If not, reduce your VM memory to 512 MB and try again. Post the result here.

Comment: When  reduced to 512 and start guest OS I am getting error `mounting local filesystems failed`

Comment: On the Host OS - open Task Manager, click the Processes Tab and sort them by memory consumption in descending order. Start the VM with 1 GB RAM as previously configured. Update your question with the screenshot from the Task Manager. Make sure all other applications are closed before that.

Comment: I have included task manager screen shot as Update 2

Answer (score 0):

Try allowing the guest OS to use both CPUs/cores in your system by sliding the "Processor(s):" slider to 2 (Second screenshot). This should balance the guest OS between both cores instead of dumping it all on the first one, which might be the cause of the slowness.